# Page number resets on chapter 1 but I don't understand why

Tags: numbering, chapters, page-numbering, report, page

I'm writing my thesis on LaTeX and according to my university guidance the page number needs to be arabic all the way throughout until the appendix. I haven't included the \pagenumberic{arabic} function anywhere but it automically restarts on my first chapter. Could you help?

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{4cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize, it},format=plain,labelfont={color=blue,bf},justification=justified, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt} % less gaps in itemize sections
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{20pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\parskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5\textfloatsep}
%\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
%  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex > #1-words.sum }%
%  \input{#1-words.sum} words%
%  }
\newcommand*{\nchapter}[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
%       \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {%
            \parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont
%           \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
%               \huge\bfseries\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par
%               \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
%           \fi
%           \interlinepenalty\@M
            \Huge\bfseries
            #1\par
            \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
        }
    }
\makeatother
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{10pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\author{Davide Vincenzo Verdolino}

\date{28 February 2021}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/header1.png}
        \begin{singlespace}
        \vspace*{2.5cm} \par
        \Huge \textbf{Title}
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         \vskip 4.0cm \par
        \large \textbf{A thesis submitted...} \par
         \vskip 4.0cm \par
        \large {author} \par
        %\large {ID}
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \vskip 0.8cm \par
        \large \normalfont {2023}
        \end{singlespace}
        \end{center}
        \end{titlepage}

        \chapter*{COVID Statement}
        \input{COVID}
        
        \tableofcontents
        \vskip 2 cm \par
        \begin{center}
            Word Count: 31,592
        \end{center}
    
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}  
        \listoftables
 
        \clearpage
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
        \listoffigures

        \nchapter{List of Abbreviations}
        \input{Abbreviations}
        
        \nchapter{Abstract}
        \input{Abstract}

        \nchapter{Declaration}
        \input{declaration}
        
        \nchapter{Copyright Statement}
        \input{Copyright}
        
        \nchapter{Acknowledgements}
        \input{Acknowledgements}      
    
        \chapter{Introduction}
        \input{Intro}

        \newpage
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \includepdf[pages=1,
            pagecommand={\chapter*{Appendix A - RRI Plan} 
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A - RRI Plan}}, 
            offset=0 -4.5cm]{RRI_Plan.pdf}
        \includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{RRI_Plan.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the titlepage environment resets the page number.

Comment: What's in the file `Intro.tex`?

Comment: Within the titlepage environment, add this command: `\setcounter{page}{5}` where the `5` is not necessarily 5, but is what that actual page number should be. Did that work?